# How to call a php ajax/function on a html button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to include inside my page a script to add a dynamic row and every time I click on add, it save the data in database.

The problem is when I insert the data and click on add row, doesn't work. 
How to write correctly this element?

```
    <div class="mainTitle">Write a customer question  : Intent</div>
  <div class="adminformTitle">
    <div class="form-group form-group-options col-md-12">
 ';

        $content .= '

   <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-hover order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>User Question</td>
            <td>Language</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-9">
            ' . HTML::inputField('user_question', null,  'placeholder="Write a short answer"'). '
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
               ' . HTML::inputField('language', null,  'placeholder="Language"'). '
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1"><a id="delete_row" class="deleteRow"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
';
```

the script ::
On click, it add a new row and save / delete data in function

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;

        $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";

            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_question' + counter + '"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="language' + counter + '"/></td>';

            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger " value="Delete"></td>';
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
            counter++;

// call files            
             $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("p").text(data);

                    }
                });
        });



        $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
            counter -= 1
        });



    function calculateRow(row) {
        var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

    }

    function calculateGrandTotal() {
        var grandTotal = 0;
        $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
            grandTotal += +$(this).val();
        });
        $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    });


    </script>
```

Comment: Remove the very last `});` in your script tag, you already closed `$(document).ready` function before `calculateRow`

Comment: Learn to use your browser's debugging toolbar.

Comment: Ok, tk, it was the problem., Change inside my code above